# JavaScript & Ajax not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have my category page. I need when i click Create category button it add new category. But when I click on the submit button nothing happend and it shows no error message. Where the problem is? Please Help

My Category blade template is

```
@extends('layouts.admin-master')


@section('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    {!! Html::style('src/css/categories.css') !!}
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <section id="category-admin">

            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="Category">Category Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Create Category</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </section>
        <section class="list">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <article>
                    <div class="category-info" data-id="{{ $category->id }}">
                        <h3>{{ $category->name }}</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="edit">
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="category-edit"><input type="text" name=""></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="danger">Delete</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                    </div>
                </article>
            @endforeach
        </section>

        @if($categories->lastPage() > 1)
            <section class="pagination">
                @if($categories->currentPage() !== 1)
                    <a href="{{ $categories->previousPageUrl() }}"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i></a>
                @endif

                @if($categories->currentPage() !== $categories->lastPage())
                    <a href="{{ $categories->nextPageUrl() }}"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                @endif
            </section>
        @endif
    </div>

@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var token = "{{ Session::token() }}";
    </script>
    {!! Html::script('src/js/categories.js') !!}
@endsection
```

My categories.js file is

```
    var docReady = setInterval(function() {
    if(document.readyState !== "complete") {
        return;
    }
    clearInterval(docReady);

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].addEventListener('click',createNewCategory);
}, 100);

function createNewCategory(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = event.target.previousElementsSibling.value;
    if(name.length === 0) {
        alert("Please create A valid Category");
        return;

    }
    ajax("POST", "/admin/blog/category/create", "name=" + name, newCategoryCreated, [name]);

}

function newCategoryCreated(params, success, responseObj) {
    location.reload();
}

function ajax(method, url, params, callback, callbackParams) {
    var http;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (http.status == 200) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
                callback(callbackParams, true, obj);
            } else if (http.status == 400) {
                alert("Category could not be saved. Please Try Again");
                callback(callbackParams, false); 
            } else {
                var obj = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
                if (obj.message) {
                    alert(obj.message);
                } else {
                    alert("please Check the name");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    http.open(method, baseUrl + url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    http.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    http.send(params + "&_token=" + token);
}
```

my route file is

```
    Route::get('/blog/categories', [
                    'uses' => 'CategoryController@getCategoryIndex',
                    'as' => 'admin.blog.categories'
            ]);
Route::post('/blog/category/create', [
                    'uses' => 'CategoryController@postCreateCategory',
                    'as' => 'admin.blog.category.create'
            ]);
```

And my Category controller is

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Category;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function getCategoryIndex() {
        $categories = Category::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.blog.categories',['categories' => $categories]);
    }

    public function postCreateCategory(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:categories'
            ]);

        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = $request['name'];
        if($category->save()) {
            return Response::json(['message' => 'Category Created'], 200);
        }
        return Response::json(['message' => 'Error during Creation'], 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because of the CSRF Token verification which comes inbuilt. You have to send the csrf token with the ajax requests. Otherwise, you have to keep the AJAX API's routes out of 'web' middleware.

Comment: Can You give the source code plz @ImeshaSudasingha

Comment: What is the **token** you are sending in the AJAX request? Is that the csrf token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the token either in the headers or as a parameter to the server. More information here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection